# Stripped reach adjustment screw on GRX RX 815 levers

Tags: shimano, shifter, brake-levers, shimano-di2, adjustment-screw

In trying to decrease the brake lever reach on my GRX Di2 shifters, I seem to have stripped the 2mm hex screws. They are located in an awkward position on the top of the shifters: https://si.shimano.com/en/dm/RX815/adjust_dual_control_lever. Please note that these are the reach adjustment screws and not the free throw adjustment screws; the latter are in a better visual position. When I now turn the screws clockwise or anti-clockwise, the levers do not move inward or outward.

I took my bike to the LBS and they were also unable to get the levers to move by turning the screws. They also verified that Shimano does not sell these screws as a replacement part.

I am wondering if these screws can be removed from the shifters and new ones installed in their place, or if they are a very specific part that would be difficult to replace if Shimano does not list them as replaceable.

Answer (score 1):

If you've stripped the heads so the tool no longer turns them, you need to get them out somehow and measure the thread. This will probably be a common metric size. The small head (by the look of the picture) makes it harder to find a direct replacement but you may get away with a grubscrew - but that takes an even smaller tool. Extracting it might mean a lot of disassemly.

Somewhere like that it's hard to tell if the screw is turning with the tool, or the tool is slipping.

On the other hand, if you've stripped the thread, the screw is probably fine, but the part of the shifter it mates with probably isn't.

For some (mechanical at least) shifters, shimano sell the main assembly. This costs nearly as much as a new shifter. But it should fix either issue.